# Selecting type(s) of account with 2nd maximum number of accounts

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Suppose we have an accounts table along with the already given values [image: here]

I want to find the type of account with second highest number of accounts. In this case, result should be `'FD'`. In case their is a contention for second highest count I need all those types in the result.

I'm not getting any idea of how to do it. I've found numerous posts for finding second highest values, say salary, in a table. But not for second highest `COUNT`.

Comment: what if 2 `type` have same count(say 5). Which one do you want to show in that case? What if highest is 5 and second highest is 4 for 2 different `type` which one you want to show in that case?

Comment: @Utsav : In that case, we'll need both. Let me edit my question here.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using cte's. Get the counts for each type as the first step. Then use `dense_rank` (to get multiple rows with same counts in case of ties) to get the rank of rows by type based on counts. Finally, select the second ranked row.

```
with counts as (
select type, count(*) cnt
from yourtable 
group by type)
, ranks as (
select type, dense_rank() over(order by cnt desc) rnk
from counts)
select type 
from ranks
where rnk = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir. 
From the query, the way I understand is, we're creating kind of a temporary table 'counts' here right. ?
Temporary since it doesn't exist at any point after this query.
So can I say kind of a 'view' is being created here ?
I'm sorry I'm totally new to this concept so asking this.

Comment: it is a temporary table which is only valid till the query executes. The results aren't stored to the database.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `row_number()` (or `dense_rank()`, depending on what "second" means when there are ties):

```
select a.*
from (select a.type, count(*) as cnt, 
             row_number() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from accounta a
      group by a.type
     ) a
where seqnum = 2;
```

In Oracle 12c+, you can use `offset`/`fetch`:

```
      select a.type, count(*) as cnt
      from accounta a
      group by a.type
      order by count(*) desc
      offset 1
      fetch first 1 row only
```